# Monthly correlations of daily data between two pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrames of daily data:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2018-01-01')
ndays = len(dates)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(ndays, 3), columns=['a','b','c'], index=dates)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(ndays, 3), columns=['a','b','c'], index=dates)
```

I would like to take the correlation of the values in each dataframe in non-overlapping monthly segments.  The return value should be a DataFrame indexed by month, with columns ['a','b','c'], where each value is the correlation of daily values in df1 and df2 for that calendar month.

I can perform this calculation looping over columns and months, but that does not sound like how a panda would do it.  Is there a way to split two dataframes based on calendar month, apply a correlation between them, and combine into a single dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a somewhat messy one-liner:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({col:pd.concat([df1[[col]],df2[[col]]],axis=1).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).apply(lambda x: x.corr().values[0,1]) for col in df1.columns})
```

Basically I create a new dataframe for each column, compute the correlation matrix each month, and then take the off-diagonal (cross-correlation) element.  There is likely a prettier way to do it, but this seems to work quickly.

Comment: hi, do you have a way to do this for two columns in the same dataset? Your way works, but it is replacing all the columns with the values instead of creating a new column